# Not sure whether it's smaller or larger - Big O notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Could one of you kindly to tell me whether it's smaller or bigger?

Is **O(N * logK)** bigger than **O(N)?**  I think it is bigger because O(NlogN) is bigger than O(N), the linear one.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely missed you used log(K) in the expression - this answer is invalid if K is not dependent on N and more, less than 1. But the you use O NlogN  in the next
sentence so lets go with N log N.

So for N = 1000 O(N) is exactly that.

O(NlogN) is logN more. Usually we are looking at a base 2 log, so O(NlogN) is about 10000.

The difference is not large but very measurable.

For N = 1,000,000
You have O(N) at 1 million

O(NlogN) would sit comfortably at 20 million.

It is helpful to know your logs to common values

```
8-bit max 255 => log 255 = 8
10 bit max 1024 => log 1024 = 10: Conclude log 1000 is very close to 10.
16 bit 65735 => log 65735 = 16
20 bits max 1024072 = 20 bits very close to 1 million.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should increase, unless for some reason K is always one, in which you wouldnt put the 'logK' in O(N*logK) and it would just be O(N) which is obv equal to O(N)

Think of it this way: What is O(N) and O(N*logK) saying?

Well O(N) is saying, for example, that you have something like an array with N elements in it. For each element you are doing an operation that takes constant time, ie adding a number to that element

While O(N*logK) is saying, not only do you need to do an operation for each element, you need to do an operation that takes logK time. Its important to note that K would denote something different than N in this case, for example you could have the array from the O(N) example plus another array with K elements. Heres a code example

```
public void SomeNLogKOperation(int[] nElements, int[] kElements){
    //for each element in nElements, ie O(N)
    for(int i = 0; i < nElements.length; i++){
        //do operation that takes O(logK) time, now we have O(N*logK)
        int val = operationThatTakesLogKTime(nElements[i], kElements)
    }
}

public void SomeNOperation(int[] nElements){
    //for each element in nElements, ie O(N)
    for(int i = 0; i < nElements.length; i++){
        //simple operation that takes O(1) time, so we have O(N*1) = O(N)
        int val = nElements[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is not asked in the context of algorithmic time complexity. Only math is required here.

So we are comparing too functions. It all depends on context. What do we know of *N* and *K*? If *K* and *N* are both free variables that tend to infinity, then yes, *O(N * log k)* is "bigger" than *O(N)*, in the sense that

*N = O(N * log k)* but

*N * log k ≠ O(N)*.

However, if *K* is some constant parameter > 0, then they are the same complexity class.

On the other hand, *K* could be *0* or negative, in which case we obtain different relationships. So you need to define/provide more context to be able to make this comparison.